# jasmine-node and bamboo - test failed

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, jasmine, bamboo, jasmine-node

I using jasmine-node for testing node app, and have integration with bamboo, but the problem is when some of the test failed bamboo reports that command jasmine-node test-name.js exits with 1 and that on bamboo job dashboard I have label testless build without reports about tests.

Also I made wrapper in node to run that command and still getting that output of executing is 1.

Can I use this wrapper for bamboo, because I'm using --junitreport flag and artifact for junit tests?
Or I can setup jasmine-node to prevent throwing error if some of the test fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the exit 0 at end of script in bamboo job.